# Physical significance of a positive (semi)-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the connection between positive (semi)-definite matrices and their transformative effects. What exactly is so special about these matrices? I know that Hermitian positive-definite matrices have strictly positive eigenvalues, but I am wondering if there is general theory about arbitrary positive-definite matrices. Thank you very much.

Comment: They share many properties, maybe most importantly they can be factored as $M=X^TX$, where there are several ways to choose $X$. They can also be represented as the matrix exponential of a symmetrical matrix like $M=\exp(X)$, where $X$ is simply symmetrical (or hermitian). These matrices are just everywhere.

Comment: Keep in mind that a quadratic form can always be written in Hermitian form.  There's seldom any real use for nonsymmetric matrices that are positive (semi) definite.

Comment: But they haven't a special interest as geometric transformations ; usual transformations (symmetries, rotations) aren't definite-positive. Their interest is elsewhere.

Comment: Besides, you should add "symmetric" to "definite positive". Without symmetry, you don't go far.

Comment: Here's one possible explanation. With the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition), every (square matrix) transformation can be decomposed into scaling along orthogonal axes, followed by a rotation/reflection. A transformation is a "scaling along orthogonal axes" if and only if it is symmetric and positive semidefinite.

Comment: @BenGrossmann clearly this because it has positive eigenvalues, as mentioned